# I'm getting separated documents of an array while using `$unwind`. How to get them as it is as arrays?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema

```
{
    "productid": {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'products', required: true},
    "itemcode": {type: String, required: true},
    "itemname": {type: String, required: true/*, index: "text"*/},
    "itemdescription": {type: String, required: true},
    "itemimgurl": {type: String, required: true},
    "mainprice": {type: Number},
    "offerprice": {type: Number, required: true},
    "unit": {type: String, required: true},
    "offertag": {type: String},
    "itemprice":[
        {
            "itemname" :{type: String, required: true},
            "unit": {type: String, required: true},
            "offerprice": {type: Number, required: true},
            "mainprice": {type: Number},
            "stock": {type: Number, required: true},
            "notify": {type: Number, required: true},
            "status": {type: Boolean, required: true},
            "itemimgurl": {type: String},
            "offertag": {type: String}
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I need to query the whole document in which document the `stock` is lessthan `notify`. How can I achieve this?

I tried like this

```
subproduct.aggregate(
       [
         {$unwind: "$itemprice"},
         {$project:
           {"productid": 1,
            "itemcode": 1,
            "itemname": 1,
            "itemdescription": 1,
            "itemimgurl": 1,
            "mainprice": 1,
            "offerprice": 1,
            "unit": 1,
            "offertag": 1,
            "itemprice":1,
            "diff": {$subtract: ["$itemprice.stock", "$itemprice.notify"]}}},
         {"$match": {'diff': {'$lt': 0}}}]
```

I'm getting response individually, but I need the response as it is like schema I mean even if one document in the array matches the query it should return the main documents as it is without splitting into different documents. Is it possible to get like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse the effects of `$unwind`, we may use the aggregation operator `$push`.

Hence try the below query,

```
 subproduct.aggregate(
             {$unwind: "$itemprice"},  
{$project:
               {
            "productid": 1,
                "itemcode": 1,
                "itemname": 1,
                "itemdescription": 1,
                "itemimgurl": 1,
                "mainprice": 1,
                "offerprice": 1,
                "unit": 1,
                "offertag": 1,
                "itemprice":1,
                "diff": {$subtract: ["$itemprice.stock", "$itemprice.notify"]}}},
             {"$match": {'diff': {'$lt': 0}}},

             {$group:{_id:"$_id",
                "productid":{"$first":"$productid"},
                 "itemcode": {"$first":"$itemcode"},
                "itemname": {"$first":"$itemname"},
                "itemdescription": {"$first":"$itemdescription"},
                "itemimgurl": {"$first":"$itemimgurl"},
                "mainprice": {"$first":"$mainprice"},
                "offerprice": {"$first":"$offerprice"},
                "unit": {"$first":"$unit"},
                "offertag": {"$first":"$offertag"},
                "itemprice":{$push:"$itemprice"}}}]);
```

Comment: Having said that, you really want the `diff` field ?
If you want the main document, you may have many itemPrice sub-documents. 

How will Mongo know which sub-document has satisfied the condition?

Comment: Without the `diff` field how can we know which sub-document's `stock` is less than `notify`? Is there any other possible way, please let me know. By the way I tried as you said, I got this error `{
  "name": "MongoError",
  "message": "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$push'",
  "errmsg": "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$push'",
  "code": 16436,
  "ok": 0
}`

Comment: Can you specify the version  of MongoDB you have ?

Comment: I'm using mlab. Its version is 3.0

Comment: I tried in my local database of version 3.2.1, got the same error `"errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$push'"`

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator, use the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)** operator in your projection to return a subset of the `itemprice` array based on the specified condition.

Take for instance the following aggregation pipeline:

```
subproduct.aggregate([ 
    { 
        "$project": { 
            "productid": 1,
            "itemcode": 1,
            "itemname": 1,
            "itemdescription": 1,
            "itemimgurl": 1,
            "mainprice": 1,
            "offerprice": 1,
            "unit": 1,
            "offertag": 1,                
            "itemprice": { 
                "$filter": {                    
                    "input": "$itemprice", 
                    "as": "el", 
                    "cond": { 
                        "$lt": [ { "$subtract": ["$$el.stock", "$$el.notify"] }, 0 ] 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I'm getting error like this `assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly o
ne field.",
        "code" : 16435
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:23:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:266:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1215:5
@(shell):1:1`

Comment: @G.Mounika There was a typo in my code which I have since rectified; had projected `itemprice` twice which caused that error.

Comment: I tried in both the ways but got the same error. I got same error with `$map` too.